# How can I convert java.class files or dalvik bytecode (dex) to LLVM-IR?

Tags: java, android, llvm, dalvik

I want to use LLVM to run passes on Android Application code .  Is there a way I can do this ? Or will I have to create my own Java front-end for LLVM ?